# C# how to filter items on ListView using textBox

Tags: c#

I want to filter the items that I added to my Listview, using my *textbox_TextChanged* Can you please show me the Codes, I am using Visual Studio 2013. tia
e.g.
First I am adding a Destination/Regularfare/Discountedfare/Baggagefare to my ListView. and my problem is *Searching* I want to search the Destinations using a TextBox.

There are no Codes inside my TextBox Search. that one I need.

And here's my Codes for adding an item to my ListView.

```
public void add(String destination, String Regulare, String Discounted, String Baggage) {
  String [] rows = { destination, Regulare, Discounted, Baggage};
  ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(rows);
  listView1.Items.Add(item);
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
  textBox1.Text = "";
  textBox2.Text = "0";
  textBox3.Text = "0";
  textBox4.Text = "0";
  MessageBox.Show("Record Added!","Saved",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
  tbDestination.Focus();
}
```

Comment: WPF, winforms, anything else?

Comment: *show me the Codes* - No, you need to *show **us** the Codes* you have created and describe the problem your having.

Comment: How did you manage to get your 'informed' badge?

Comment: Please pardon me, I am new here in Stack Over Flow, I was Edit my early post, pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other posters were saying, we don't know what your tech stack is or what problem you're trying to solve. Have you tried binding your list to a data source? Let's say you have a text box and a submit button for filtering. The user enters "California" into the text box and presses *submit*. You'll have a click handler in the code behind that invokes a DataBind() on your list. The method for your data bind will get the value of the textbox/hidden field and use it to return a conditional data structure that is then used to populate your list. You could even have a *clear* button that resets the filtering using the same method.

But it's been 16 days now, so you've probably already solved the problem. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Hı , Try this two way

First :

```
private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call FindItemWithText with the contents of the textbox.
    ListViewItem foundItem =
        textListView.FindItemWithText(searchBox.Text, false, 0, true);
    if (foundItem != null)
    {
        textListView.TopItem = foundItem;
    }
}
```

Second :

```
void yourListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    // Find the an item above where the user clicked.
    ListViewItem foundItem =
        iconListView.FindNearestItem(SearchDirectionHint.Up, e.X, e.Y);

    if (foundItem != null)
        previousItemBox.Text = foundItem.Text;
    else
        previousItemBox.Text = "No item found";
}
```